# SWTableviewcell - call animation method without swiping or selecting

Tags: uitableview, animation, tableview

I have been using SWTableViewCell in a project but I wanted to make the user aware that the swipe function is available on a particular UITableview. I am hoping to do this by momentarily revealing the swipe view animation of the first tableviewcell when the tableview is loaded. So for example the tableview will load, the right utility Button will open for cell 0, then momentarily hide again - thereby showing the user that there is an option to swipe the cell to reveal a 'right utility button'. I am thinking that could achieve this by using a simple timer and by triggering the appropriate methods.
However, I need some direction as to which methods to call for this to work. I have tried the following but this has not actioned the animation itself:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
GenericTableViewCell6 *cell = (GenericTableViewCell6 *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[ self swipeableTableViewCell:cell scrollingToState:2];
```

I have tried tweaking this code to see if i can action the animation - but again this tweak has not worked for me.

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
GenericTableViewCell6 *cell = (GenericTableViewCell6 *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell showRightUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
```

I would be very grateful for any guidance or input on this. please message if you need any further information. 
many thanks
james.

Answer (score 0):

After a few strong coffees I figured this one out. Here is my solution:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row== 0) {
        [cell showRightUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];


        double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [cell showLeftUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];

        });

    }

}
```